# Make Eclipse wrap selected text in brackets

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm using Eclipse Kepler.

It takes too long to go from the start of the block of the code to the end so I can add opening and closing  brackets. I'm using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> and the arrow keys to select my blocks, but I don't have a hotkey or anything to wrap the selection with brackets. I'd love to have some command such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>(</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd> to do this, but I can't find the way to make them.

Templates can't help me here. Preferences > General > Keys can't bind anything in the editor. Yes, I know about the <kbd>Home</kbd> and <kbd>End</kbd> buttons; this question is not about them.

I made a template:

```
(${word_selection})${cursor}
```

This helps a bit. However, I have to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, then <kbd>Up Arrow</kbd>, then <kbd>Enter</kbd>, to use. It also only works for parentheses; if I wanted to try with, say, angle braces, it wouldn't work.

As far as I see, there is no way to bind this template with a shortcut, except making a plugin for eclipse.

Comment: Have you tried the `Edit`->`Expand Selection To` menu?

Comment: That doesn't work for me. I want the selection to become in brackets, not to expand it.

Answer (score 1):

Using `${line_selection}` I've made a template just like yours, and it works:

```
{
    ${line_selection}${cursor}
}
```

Also, I tried using <> instead of {} and it works.